# Cant override bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap to give style to my grid but it makes it cover all the page. I tried to make the div containing the table smaller but it didnt work. How can I override bootstrap style?

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='calendar'>
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/mystyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>


</head>

<body >
    <div class='wrapper' ng-controller='GridCtrl as grid'>
     <div class="week-calendar">
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" width="100">
      <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in grid.rows">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my StyleSheet to override bootstrap

```
.week-calendar{
  width: 400;
}

.table-striped tbody tr.active:nth-child(odd) td, .table-striped tbody tr.active:nth-child(odd) th {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap CSS must be loaded in a separate CSS after bootstrap.css as others have stated. With that in mind if bootstrap references a style CSS you don't want to use you MUST override it with a separate CSS.  Here is a good example. Right out of the box Bootstrap's Fieldsets with Legends are all screwed up. Here's bootstrap's CSS.

HOW TO FIX BOOTSTRAP'S FIELDSETS AND LEGEND USING CSS

```
  fieldset {
  padding: .35em .625em .75em;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  }

  legend {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  }
```

But this is really what I want the fieldsets styled as so I had to override it by using this:

```
fieldset {  
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
    }

    legend {
       font-weight:bold;
       padding:0px 6px 0px 6px;
       font-size: 15px;
       width: auto;
       border-bottom: none;
       margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `week-calendar` class needs to have a unit of measurement.

```
.week-calendar{
  width: 400px;
}
```

And you're looking for a `tr.active` class which doesn't exist in your code.

If you change your `<tr>` class to `<tr class="active" ng-repeat="row in grid.rows">` it will give you your desired result.  However note that this will make all of the table cells have your custom CSS styling.

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/bKU4MQzGfN)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap intentionally makes it difficult to override their CSS.

Add an or extra class, then use their classes to override if needed with your new attr.

Also, 400 what? pixels? %? :)

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't make it intentionally difficult.  Just create your own CSS file and include it after you load your Bootstrap stylesheet. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_styles.css">`

Comment: by 'make it difficult' i meant the names they use, and the cascading nature of the way these frameworks are built. yes, adding another stylesheet after bootstrap can help with specificity overriding.

Comment: Yeah, why do these frameworks use a cascading nature for their CSS? Baffling!